# pigrc feature available?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

Is there a way to "automatically" set certain variables when i invoke the pig grunt intractive shell. I understand that we could use the define/default command to but then it is manual. Usecase could be the setting various variables that point to different HDFS path. I also understand that such an option can be used when calling the pig file using

> pig -param_file  -f somefile.pig

. But even if i use the -param_file during invoking the pig shell it does not work (pig -param_file ).

What i am looking for is kind of ".hiverc" file feature, do we have one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2456) you already have it. But you need to be on pig-0.11.0(or later) if you want to have this working.